# SVG transition issues in Chrome and Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, transition, opera

I have an inline SVG and I want to animate it on hover. The way it's supposed to look, after you hover, a circle grows in size and inverts the SVG. I.e. what was opaque is now transparent. It's done by using a CSS transition on the radius parameter of a circle inside a mask.

The animation works flawlessly in Safari, but not in Chrome and Opera. In these browsers, it acts very weird. In short, it seems to only repaint the SVG when the cursor leaves the screen.

Firefox does nothing at all, but I'd attribute that to the lack of vendeor prefixes.

Thank you for your help in advance!

How can I remedy this? What alternative approaches I can take?

Here is a Pen of it (doesn't seem to animate): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGNaBw

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        *
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;

            background: #0F0F0F;
        }

        svg
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 60%;
            height:60%;

            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        }

        #svg_tm
        {
            transition: r 350ms;
        }

        svg:hover #svg_tm
        {
            r: 50;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <defs>
                <circle id="svg_tm" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>
                <path id="svg_ts" d="M86.915 27.103c-2.716 1.204-5.636 2.02-8.7 2.385 3.128-1.875 5.53-4.843 6.66-8.38-2.926 1.735-6.168 2.996-9.618 3.675C72.494 21.84 68.557 20 64.2 20c-8.365 0-15.147 6.782-15.147 15.147 0 1.187.134 2.343.392 3.452-12.588-.633-23.75-6.663-31.22-15.827-1.304 2.237-2.05 4.838-2.05 7.615 0 5.255 2.673 9.89 6.737 12.607-2.482-.08-4.818-.76-6.86-1.894l-.002.19c0 7.34 5.222 13.462 12.15 14.854-1.27.346-2.608.53-3.99.53-.976 0-1.925-.094-2.85-.27C23.29 62.42 28.883 66.8 35.51 66.92c-5.184 4.063-11.715 6.484-18.812 6.484-1.222 0-2.428-.07-3.613-.21C19.788 77.492 27.75 80 36.305 80 64.164 80 79.4 56.92 79.4 36.903c0-.657-.014-1.31-.043-1.96 2.96-2.135 5.527-4.803 7.558-7.84"/>
                <mask id="svg_ta">
                    <use xlink:href="#svg_ts" fill="#fff"></use>
                    <use xlink:href="#svg_tm"></use>
                </mask>
                <mask id="svg_tb">
                    <use xlink:href="#svg_tm" fill="#fff"></use>
                    <use xlink:href="#svg_ts"></use>
                </mask>
            </defs>
            <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#F0F0F0" mask="url(#svg_ta)"></circle>
            <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#F0F0F0" mask="url(#svg_tb)"></circle>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what the `r` in  `transition: r 350ms;`  stands for ?

Comment: It's the radius property of the animated circle. That's how it's called in SVG.

Comment: Raise a Chrome bug on their bugtracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SVG (1.1) you can't modify attributes like `r` with CSS. Only style properties.

[List of SVG style properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html)

The upcoming SVG2 spec allows it, and some browsers have started implementing it, but most have not.

You will need to use another method to animate your radius.